# Ubuntu, Python script, how to run after boot and using update-rc.d

Tags: ubuntu, boot, runlevel

I have a python script in /etc/init.d/test.py.  I want to run this script and network access is required since I clone from github.

So...I am confused about using this command:

```
 sudo update-rc.d test.py start NN rl
```

I assume I want run level 3?  What is hte NN?  In essence, should the update-rc.d line look like?  I would like it last on bootup.  That is the last script that should be run.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The NN is the numeric prefix you want; to load near the end of the statrup sequence, use the highest possible number, 99.  Use `defaults` instead of `start` and hard-coding runlevel 3 for a reasonable interactive script. See further http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

Ideally, your script should have the headers for determining its dependencies; then it will be possible to run it as soon as possible, i.e. when its dependencies are satisfied. Again, read the man page for pointers.